# Как заменить текст на видео при помощи ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Нужно заменить текст на видео в определенный момент, например текст на  движущемуся автомобиле.

Comment: А если бы текст был просто на статической картинке, смогли бы?

Comment: да, при помощи фильтра drawtext и наложения фона

Comment: простой способ - извлекаете все фреймы - `ffmpeg -i file.mpg -r 1/1 $filename%03d.bmp`, потом процессите их своим способом, а потом упаковываете назад в видео.

Сложный способ - написать свой фильтр.